# Public variable goes out of scope

Tags: vba, ms-access

My public variables are losing scope when execution moves to a sub in a different module. I can't fathom why this is happening.

Module A:

```
Option Compare Database

Public db As DAO.Database
Public xlApp As Excel.Application

Sub Main()

Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = CurrentDb

ProcessFiles ' upload the data from the report files
AppendToPentana ' transfer the data from the main tables to the pentana export table
ProduceFinalExport ' export the final data to Excel

End Sub
```

Module B:

```
Sub ProcessFiles()

Dim recSet As Recordset

' open a recordset containing keywords to look for in the file names to identify the area
Set recSet = db.OpenRecordset("tblFiles")

' rest of code

End Sub
```

In module B the variable db has been set to Nothing and I get an object ref error. I've tried using the older 'Global' declaration rather than Public with the same result.

Public variables are commonly used, I don't get what's going wrong here.

Comment: `Global` is *exactly* the same as `Public` (except it can't be used everywhere `Public` can). The advent of `Public` made `Global` obsolete, a few decades ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Sub Main()

Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = CurrentDb
```

You have an additional **local** variable `db` in `Main`, and this is the one you set. Local variables have precedence over global ones.

Just remove that `Dim` line from `Main` and it will work.

Comment: Doh! I need a coffee :) Thanks

Comment: For the record, remove the `Dim` line in entirety. Don't just remove the `Dim` (for anyone who might come across this in the future).